# Passing user inputted params into find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form the has the users import a score.  I am wanting that score to be passed into the sql string.  This is what I have so far.

```
numbers = NumbersTest.find_by_sql('select phone_number, person_id from numbers_tests where score = ?', params[:score])
```

that keeps giving me a `undefined method empty?' for nil:NilClass` error.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ive tried both.  Some documentation has []

Comment: `numbers = NumbersTest.find_by_sql(['select phone_number, person_id from numbers_tests where score = ?', params[:score]])` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do a normal Active Record query:

```
numbers = NumbersTest.select(:phone_number, :person_id).where(score: params[:score])
```